# When is "declare" used in C++?

Tags: c++, declaration

This is probably a silly question, but it is difficult to search for, given its keywords. I was glancing at some C++ code today and saw some stuff being declared at the top of a function in the following way:

```
declare(some stuff);
```

When is this used in C++?

Comment: Probably a macro, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword

Comment: Looks like it might be a macro.  I haven't seen this before

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no such keyword in C++.

Most likely, it was a macro defined (with `#define`) elsewhere in the headers that were included before that line.